# Modulo pattern with zero skipped

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Is there a way to find a modular partern in which 0 doesn't exist.

For eg : mod(x,6)
012345012345....
I'd like : 
1234512345....

I need it for a rotation in a list but I cant use 0

Thanks !

Comment: Take modulo 5 and then add 1.

Comment: @Théophile et comment est ce que je peux le faire avec de façon décroissante ?

Comment: Pour les mettre en ordre décroissant, vous pourriez utiliser $5-\text{mod}(x,5)$, ce qui donne 5432154321...